# Is $x^0$ a polynomial?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, definition, algebraic-numbers

On the one hand I have seen this called a "constant polynomial" since $x^0 = 1$ for any $x$. But I would have thought this was a bad idea, because then any number can be considered the root of the polynomial 
$x^0 - 1$ and so every number is "algebraic" in this sense. So should $x^0$ be a polynomial or not?

Comment: A number is algebraic iff it is a root of a  polynomial **other than** the constant $0$.

Comment: It is simply notation as a convenience to say $x^0 = 1$.  If you dislike that notation, it would be understandable for you to avoid using it.  Of course $1$ is a polynomial.

Comment: If we didn't consider constant polynomials to be polynomials, the standard description of polynomial division wouldn't work without a complicated circumlocution for what would become a special case when the divisor is a linear polynomial $(x - a)$. Many other standard results would require an extra special case. That would be hideous compared with the tiny price paid for the accepted definition of algebraic number as given in Robert's answer.